# Want to use apache, ISP blocking port 80

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, redirection

I am attempting to set up a small web server on my home network, but my ISP is blocking incoming port 80 ( and no, i'm not paying $50/month extra for them to unblock it).

I am looking for some ways around this, obviously I can change the port # but I don't find this ideal.

really appreciate any ideas for this

Comment: port 443 and make the entire site SSL by default?

Comment: If they block port 80, they probably block 443 too :)

Answer (score 5):

The hosting industry is a billion dollar industry largely because hosting at home is non-ideal. You have horrible upload bandwidth which translates to horrible download speeds for your site visitors. You have to configure NAT with port forwarding, etc, etc.

Get a cheap VPS account if you are trying to learn about server administration. Get a shared hosting account if you are trying to learn about web design, development. Get a free blog account at wordpress.com if you are trying to blog strictly for bloggings sake.

Comment: -1 He never said anything about high volume traffic, blogging, or even imply more than 1 user.  The question is only about Apache hosting over port 80.

Answer (score 4):

First, check your terms of service.  Bypassing this block may violate them.

Second, are you really prepare for exposing your home network to incoming traffic?  Are you ready to manage all the security required?  Can you handle it when a security crack creates a bot network or site hosting illegal material in your home and your ISP and/or the law show up to discuss it?

Third, there are a variety of free or very low cost services for you to host your own blog ranging from blogger to wordpress.com to livejournal for basic blogs to full fledged hosting services like Dreamhost (usually under $10 for the first year) to Grokthis.net ($6 month for fairly nice services).

Unless you have a real business reason to host it at home and the expertise necessary to administer a network at that level, spend the $10 or less a month.  You'll save yourself stomach lining and probably money in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning on using your web server for VERY SMALL SCALE use ONLY, then you can do the following:
Buy a domain and use a redirection service (I used no-ip.org) to take standard http requests (port 80) to your router on whatever port you choose. As posters above mentioned, though, you're likely violating the terms of service, but if you're just trying to share some small bits of content with friends or family and you take necessary precautions to protect your network from the wild, you can probably forward safely.

I did this for a class in which I needed to host a Rails application: The website hits the wild simply by turning on the computer, and gets pulled when I get home from class to minimize the amount of time in which it's exposed to the wild.

Comment: +1 Link: http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html

Answer (score 3):

free web hosting turns up a lot of answers on google, you could put your home server ip/allowed port in an iframe on one of these servers

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar situation as my provider blocks port 80 as well. If your Internet domain provider allows URL redirect then this solution will work for you. Here is what I did to bypass this restriction:

I set up Apache to listen on port 88 and verified that it worked by going to my internal IP `192.168.1.10:88` and it worked. I then opened port 88 in my router to allow incoming traffic to this port.

The next step is to go to your Internet domain provider and create `A` record and `WWW` records using your public IP (I don't even use dyDNS as my ISP rarely changes IPs unless you unplug your router for more than 12 hours). You create two URL redirect records with your site followed by port number as follows:

```
Record
Type      Host
------    ----
A         http://example.com:88 
WWW       www.example.com:88
```

Once the DNS records are updated (it took about an hour in my case) you should be able to visit your site by just typing the URL `example.com` in the address bar. Also, don't forget to enable masking otherwise visitors will see that you are running on a non-standard port.

Comment: Your first paragraph is commentary rather than part of the solution, and readers may think this is just a rant and not read further.  If you feel the need to post it, it would be more appropriate in a comment on your post.

Comment: In that case all other comments should be adjusted as they discourage the person who requested for help and instead of actual solution they say lots of reasons of why not to do it rather than help.

Comment: This is an ancient question.  The site standards have been refined a lot since then.  In general, answers should focus on the solution and avoid commentary about other users or the nature of their answers (as opposed to addressing facts within other answers).  The first paragraph doesn't add anything useful to your answer and may turn off some readers.  It's about the answering "process", so if it goes anywhere, that should be in a comment.  It isn't part of your solution.

Comment: @Zebra This is a useful answer.  I hope you don't mind the editing to help others focus on your helpful contribution.  Welcome to Super User and thanks for contributing.

Comment: @Zebra One question.  A "www" record is actually an **A** record where the host portion of the record is `www`.  Are the two records you're referring to perhaps both A records, the first for the **@ (None** host and the second the **WWW** host?  This would make more sense because creating those two records would capture visitors who used `www.example.com` as well as `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your best bet is to go someplace like godaddy and get a cheap hosting plan - they can run you as little as $5/month these days.